# perform two foreach loops on same data

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to iterate through data pulled from an mssql database twice in my php, but I find that when I perform the first foreach loop the array is then listed as empty as the array pointer has moved through the entire array.

In essence I have this:

```
$rstGold = $rstGold2 = getFeatured();

foreach($rstGold as $store){
//proccessing here
}

foreach($rstGold2 as $store){
//proccessing here
}
```

get featured is a sql query returning results using the mssql-PDO driver.

```
function getFeatured(){
             global $db, $debug;

             $query = //sql query

             return $db->query($query);
}
```

I need a way to iterate through the results of getFeatured() twice, with them remaining in the same order.  My sql query randomizes the results so I cannot perform a second sql query.

While writing this I found a way to perform all of the processing in the same loop, but would still like to know what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: foreach does not change the original array, so the issue is inside your loop, and you have shown no code for that

Comment: `foreach` actually resets the array on its first iteration so the second `foreach` loop should be working as intended.  could you post more code?

Comment: All I was doing inside the loops were print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php), per the docs:

> When you want to iterate over the same array multiple times you need
>   to instantiate ArrayObject and let it create ArrayIterator instances
>   that refer to it either by using foreach or by calling its
>   getIterator() method manually.

And the example follows:

```
<?php
$fruits = array(
    "apple" => "yummy",
    "orange" => "ah ya, nice",
    "grape" => "wow, I love it!",
    "plum" => "nah, not me"
);
$obj = new ArrayObject( $fruits );
$it = $obj->getIterator();

// How many items are we iterating over?

echo "Iterating over: " . $obj->count() . " values\n";

// Iterate over the values in the ArrayObject:
while( $it->valid() )
{
    echo $it->key() . "=" . $it->current() . "\n";
    $it->next();
}

// The good thing here is that it can be iterated with foreach loop

foreach ($it as $key=>$val)
echo $key.":".$val."\n";
```

The class also has a [method to reset the pointer to the beginning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.rewind.php) called `rewind`, used as follows:

```
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

$iterator->next();
echo $iterator->key(); //1

$iterator->rewind(); //rewinding to the begining
```

Hope that helps.